# 'TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer' when updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to pass a Map to attributes and this error `TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer` is occurring.  Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

This code was working until I did a migration from Heroku Bamboo to Heroku Cedar (But the version of Rails and Ruby are the same down to the specific build (1.9.2p320 -> 1.9.2p321 and Rails 3.0.20)

It's obvious that it's occurring because the Map that is being handled by this line `attribute_ids = attributes_collection.map {|a| a['id'] || a[:id] }.compact`  But 'a' eventually returns just a string and that causes the error.

I included the Map that is being handled and the stacktrace of the error . https://gist.github.com/akinsgre/10994359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I sort of figured out the problem... now I need to figure out how to fix the existing records.

The nested_attributes had changed, at some point, from has_one to has_many; so the "bad" maps have this

```
"party_attributes" => {
                "profile" => "e04aaa50c9c3501de345fb9b468e53d5371e2e83e098bd2d67de4be39531616a"
            }
```

The good maps have

```
 "party_attributes" => {
                "0" => {
                    "profile" => "e04aaa50c9c3501de345fb9b468e53d5371e2e83e098bd2d67de4be39531616a"
                },
                "1" => {
                    "profile" => "8cdcde33e1315a77894d5a9601cff114b97dd5da9ca5f1c87ea7be3ea81398b3"
                }
```

Comment: Just wrote a function to crawl the Hash and modify the records.